# how to add a TF for odom --> base_link?

Tags: ros, navigation, rviz, odometry, amcl

I'm trying to do amcl and currently my map is not working and found the solution, which is the odom --> base_link TF currently not found, how do I create a odom --> base_link TF?

Currently having a map --> base_link TF not found also
here are some pics

amcl_params_diff.yaml:

```
use_map_topic: true

odom_frame_id: "odom"
base_frame_id: "base_link"
global_frame_id: "map"

## Publish scans from best pose at a max of 10 Hz
odom_model_type: "omni"
odom_alpha5: 0.2
gui_publish_rate: 10.0
laser_max_beams: 60
laser_max_range: 60.0
min_particles: 500
max_particles: 2000
kld_err: 0.05
kld_z: 0.99
odom_alpha1: 0.2
odom_alpha2: 0.2
## translation std dev, m 
odom_alpha3: 0.2
odom_alpha4: 0.2
laser_z_hit: 0.5
laser_z_short: 0.05
laser_z_max: 0.05
laser_z_rand: 0.5
laser_sigma_hit: 0.2
laser_lambda_short: 0.1
laser_model_type: "likelihood_field" # "likelihood_field" or "beam"
laser_likelihood_max_dist: 2.0
update_min_d: 0.25
update_min_a: 0.5

resample_interval: 1

## Increase tolerance because the computer can get quite busy 
transform_tolerance: 0.2
recovery_alpha_slow: 0.0
recovery_alpha_fast: 0.0
```

Picture of terminal when launching file:

[image: terminal output]

The output I see in rviz:

[image: rviz output]

The current tf tree I'm seeing:

[image: current tf tree]

Comment: In my comment to one of your earlier posts, I pointed you to the robot setup tutorial, which is was I used to setup a realworld robot. 

wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup 

It's an excellent tutorial and will go a long way towards answering your question.

Comment: @billy yeap thankyou for the help. i did go through the tutorial but mine wouldnt work out , not sure why, but theres lots of errors thats why im trying to find another way to do it. pretty problematic since i need the odom frame only but i cant find solutions

Comment: my /map frame is also missing and im not sure how to find it

Comment: please include yaml file as text, not as a link ... format it as code ... also copy the pictures into the question, not into Google drive ... use the button that has the moon and mountains

Comment: There is no otherway to do it. That tutorial is as entry-level as it gets and provides the minimum on what is required to get navigation running. It is a lot, and also the minimum required.

Comment: It looks like you may have accidentally created two accounts ([nolan](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/users/37125/nolan) & [nolan](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/users/37128/nolan)). Stack Exchange only allows individuals to use one account, so please follow the instructions at [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts)
Moderators [can't merge accounts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/272251) for you, but may delete accounts they believe to be [sock puppets](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/57685/138432).